# how to calculate color difference in percentage for Less

Tags: html, css, colors, less

Say i have two colors `#595b5c` and `#424545`. I want to know the percentage difference between them, how to do that? The reason being i want to use [lighten](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-lighten) and [darken](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-darken) functions of less which take percentage as a parameter.

Eg:

```
@darkgrey1: #595b5c;
@darkgrey2: darken(@darkgrey1,10%);
```

How do i know by how much percent `#424545` is darker than `#595b5c`

Comment: In simple case it's: `delta: (lightness(#595b5c) - lightness(#424545));`.

Comment: @seven-phases-max dont you think it wont be that simple as per @ Guffa below?

Comment: It depends, for me it will take about 4 seconds to write this code, press F5 and see the result. For a @Gufaa methos it will take 2-5 minutes to remember/find an online converter link :) (OK, OK, half-joking).

Comment: @seven-phases-max lol. I was talking of the concept. I felt Guffa had a good point! If i just darken or lighten i cant get one color from another

Comment: Sure, more over the definition of "lightness" and "darkness" may differ and HSL only one of several color models.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The lighten and darken functions changes the lightness of the color in the HSL color space. If you convert each color to HSL, you will see how much the lightness differs.

I used an online [RGB to HSL converter](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsl.htm).

The color `#595b5c` (`rgb(89,91,92)`) is `hsl(200,1.7,35.5)`.

The color `#424545` (`rgb(66,69,69)`) is `hsl(180,2.2,26.5)`.

So, the difference in lightness is 9.0 percent units.

Note that `#424545` doesn't have the exact hue and saturation as `#595b5c`. If you darken one you won't get exactly the other.

Comment: Or use this link http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/index.htm to be able to input hex colour values directly. Anyway, thanks for reference.

Comment: Alternatively, one can use a computer to do the math :) Check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33933623/25427) for a tool that reports the colors directly.

Answer (score 46):

I have to solve the exact same problem on a daily basis, so I created a [tool for color function suggestions](https://ofcodeandcolor.com/cuttle/). It lists most of the LESS functions that get from one color to another, so that you can focus on whether using `darken` or `softlight` makes more sense for your use-case.

[image: Suggest LESS color function]

(Cuttlefish have amazing color changing abilities, thus the name / logo)

Comment: Thanks a lot! +1. This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Can be done in many different ways but here is a solution using javascript:

```
function color_meter(cwith, ccolor) {

    if (!cwith && !ccolor) return;

    var _cwith  = (cwith.charAt(0)=="#") ? cwith.substring(1,7) : cwith;
    var _ccolor = (ccolor.charAt(0)=="#") ? ccolor.substring(1,7) : ccolor;

    var _r = parseInt(_cwith.substring(0,2), 16);
    var _g = parseInt(_cwith.substring(2,4), 16);
    var _b = parseInt(_cwith.substring(4,6), 16);

    var __r = parseInt(_ccolor.substring(0,2), 16);
    var __g = parseInt(_ccolor.substring(2,4), 16);
    var __b = parseInt(_ccolor.substring(4,6), 16);

    var p1 = (_r / 255) * 100;
    var p2 = (_g / 255) * 100;
    var p3 = (_b / 255) * 100;

    var perc1 = Math.round((p1 + p2 + p3) / 3);

    var p1 = (__r / 255) * 100;
    var p2 = (__g / 255) * 100;
    var p3 = (__b / 255) * 100;

    var perc2 = Math.round((p1 + p2 + p3) / 3);

    return Math.abs(perc1 - perc2);   
    }
```

Here is the [Source](https://gist.github.com/mailtruck/2411659)